# Printing recursive file and folder count in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare two sets of folders to determine discrepancies in file and folder counts. I have found a command that will output the data I am looking for, but cannot find a way to print it to a file. Here is the command I am using currently:

```
dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

This is getting me the desired data but I need to find a way to print this to a text file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the use of the `Write-Host` cmdlet, which bypasses almost all pipeline handling.  In this case, it is also unnecessary, as any output that isn't used by a cmdlet is automatically passed into the pipeline (or to the console if there's nothing further).

Here is your code rewritten to output a string to the pipeline instead of using Write-Host.  This uses PowerShell's string subexpression operator `$()`.  At the console, it will look the same, but it can be piped to a file or other cmdlet.

```
gci -Recurse -Directory | %{ "$($_.FullName) $((gci $_.FullName).Count)" }
```

You may also find it useful to put the data into a PSCustomObject.  Once you have the object, you can do further processing such as sorting or filtering based on the count.

```
$folders = gci -Recurse -Directory | %{ [PSCustomObject]@{Name=$_.FullName; Count=(dir $_.FullName).Count }}

$folders | sort Count
$folders | where Count -ne 0
```

*Some notes on idioms: `dir` is an alias for `Get-Childitem`, as is `gci`.  Using `gci`'s `-Directory` parameter is the best way to list only directories, rather than the `PSIsContainer` check. Finally, `Measure-Object` is unnecessary. You can take the `Count` of the file listing directly.*

*See also [Write-Host Considered Harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) from the inventor of PowerShell*